# Simple API Image Upload to Google Drive

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I've written the following code to upload an image to my own Google Drive using a [service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/).

My code is returning successfully, giving me an `ID` back but there's nothing appearing on my actual Google Drive.

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_file_location, scopes=scope)
    service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    return service


def setup_upload():
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    key_file_location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(settings.BASE_DIR), 'common/my-json-file.json')
    service = get_service('drive', 'v3', scope, key_file_location)

    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(settings.BASE_DIR), 'common/apple.png')

    file_metadata = {'name': 'apple.png'}
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype="image/png")
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print(file.get('id')) #this returns an actual ID

setup_upload()
```

I do get a long `ID` string back from the last line of `setup_upload()`. But nothing is appearing on my actual Google Drive. I'm expecting to see the `apple.png` file pop up in my home directory.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/) you linked to:
"You can take the service account email address and give it access to a directory on your Google drive. It will then be allowed to upload to that directory, but you wont have access to the files. You will need to complete a second step and give yourself personally permission to access those files by updating or patching the file permissions."

Have you given the service account access to the place where you want to write the file? If you haven't specified where to upload the file to, the service account may just be uploading the file into its own Drive.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you clarify how exactly I can give the service account access to the place where I want to write to? I thought the `scope` variable would be enough, and it would automatically go in the root google drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user2705223's answer, if you want to be able to access the files it uploads, then you must grant yourself access to them through the service account. Check if you had a successful login credentials and authorize the service account with right scope. You can try following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts) to help you do the authorization to make API requests.